# Is it possible to use Mahalanobis Transformation using the data I have available?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, python, autocorrelation, mahalanobis

My datasets contain of 5 regional spot electricity prices and 2 fixed electricity prices. I also have a time variable going week to week from 2010 to the end of 2021. Is there any way to use the data I have available to use the Mahalanobis Transformation and have the autocorrelation from my variables removed? My goal is to be able to compare the regional prices for for example region 1 against the fixed price contracts with uncorrelated data.

I also have been thinking of if it's possible to use the transformation if I use for example my first variable and then against the same variable only with 1 lag, would that be possible or is there any other way?

I can add that down below is my code if you are familiar with python, but it's not my main question just a bonus:

```
def mahalanobis_transform(data):
    # Calculate the mean of the data
    mean_data = np.mean(data, axis=0)

    # Calculate the covariance matrix
    cov_matrix = np.cov(data, rowvar=False)

    # Calculate the inverse square root of the covariance matrix
    inv_sqrt_cov = 1 / np.sqrt(cov_matrix)

    # Perform the Mahalanobis transformation for a scalar covariance matrix
    transformed_data = (data - mean_data) * inv_sqrt_cov

    return transformed_data
```

All answers are greatly appreciated!